# Clion, cmake DSO missing when building simple2d

Tags: cmake, clion

I have started with a project that are using the simple2d library (https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d). But when I try to build my small example project I get a DSO missing error. I think a have manage to link the dependencies for simple2d, but apparently I'm still some thing.

Here is the output:

```
> ====================[ Build | c_game | Debug ]==================================
/home/fredrik/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/192.5728.100/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/fredrik/Repos/c_game/cmake-build-debug --target c_game -- -j 2 -m
[ 50%] Linking C executable c_game
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libsimple2d.a(gl.o): undefined reference to symbol 'fmin@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/c_game.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'c_game' failed
make[3]: *** [c_game] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/c_game.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/c_game.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/c_game.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/c_game.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'c_game' failed
make: *** [c_game] Error 2
```

And here is my CMakeList.txt, I hope someone can help me.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(c_game C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(c_game main.c)

find_library(SIMPLE2D_LIB libsimple2d.a /usr/local/lib)
message(${SIMPLE2D_LIB})
message(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(c_game PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(c_game ${SIMPLE2D_LIB} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: "I think a have manage to link the dependencies for simple2d" - I don't see linking with `libm`. The linker complains exactly about this linking: `//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`.

Comment: I added libm with the following: target_link_libraries(c_game ${SIMPLE2D_LIB} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} m) But then I get undefined reference to the other libraries I linked.

Comment: So you need to link that other libraries too.

Comment: I think I have done that, is there any easy way to find out which libraries that are missing?

Comment: I would like to see the answer to this as I have a similar error but with libstdc++.so.6 as I am learning C++... an answer to this would be helpful!